# "argument contains uninitialised data" when setting frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS development and handling memory leaks. In my project while analysing the project I got some memory leaks. But I could not fix the below logic error at below code.

```
CGRect labelframe;


if ([questonmod.questionType isEqualToString:@"type1"])
{
    nooflinesint=questonmod.questiontext.length/20;

    if (nooflinesint<1)
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+2;
    }
    else
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+1;
    }

    labelframe= CGRectMake(5, 0, cell.frame.size.width-10, nooflinesint*18);


}
else if([questonmod.questionType isEqualToString:@"type2"])
{

    nooflinesint=questonmod.questiontext.length/10;

    if (nooflinesint<1)
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+2;
    }
    else
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+1;
    }
    labelframe= CGRectMake(5,0,cell.frame.size.width-155,nooflinesint*16);

}


cell.questionlabel.frame=labelframe; //at this line I got below error.
```

I am getting "Passed-by-value struct argument contains uninitialised data(e.g., via the field chain:'origin.x')" error description.

Please suggest how can I fix above issue..

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: @Aly...YES I am using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `CGRect labelframe;` like this

```
CGRect labelframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

or

```
CGRect labelframe = CGRectZero;
```

or adding else condition  LIKE BELOW would solve your problem

```
if ([questonmod.questionType isEqualToString:@"type1"])
{
    nooflinesint=questonmod.questiontext.length/20;

    if (nooflinesint<1)
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+2;
    }
    else
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+1;
    }

    labelframe= CGRectMake(5, 0, cell.frame.size.width-10, nooflinesint*18);


}
else if([questonmod.questionType isEqualToString:@"type2"])
{

    nooflinesint=questonmod.questiontext.length/10;

    if (nooflinesint<1)
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+2;
    }
    else
    {
        nooflinesint=nooflinesint+1;
    }
    labelframe= CGRectMake(5,0,cell.frame.size.width-155,nooflinesint*16);

}
else{
  labelframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


cell.questionlabel.frame=labelframe;
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that the compiler can't be sure that one of the if/else-if blocks is ever reached, in which case, `labelframe` would still be uninitialized. You can add an other else or just init the `labelframe` to `CGRectZero`. It is not a memory error but a logic one.

Comment: @samir The above comment is wrong. Because there is an 'else' clause, the compiler can be 100% assured that the labelframe will receive a value. The problem is that you need to initialise the labeframe correctly using: CGRect labelframe = ...

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with memory leaks. The code above does not guarantee to set up `labelFrame`, because it has an if, then an else if. If neither condition is true, the frame will not be initialised.

Set up a default frame or add a final else clause.